# When a field is marked with type TreeListEx and if we add some media items to that field , end result URL doesnt contain HASH value

Tags: tree-list, mediaurls

When a field is marked with type TreeListEx  and if we add some media items to that field , end result URL doesnt contain HASH value even if Media.Request.Protection.Enabled is set as true.